# Comment traduire « on-topic » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, adjectifs

Il me semble avoir vu une traduction en français de l'expression anglaise « *on-topic* » pour décrire des questions qui sont appropriées pour le site, mais maintenant je ne peux pas le trouver.  Donc que suggérez-vous pour traduire cette expression en français ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hors_sujet) propose "à propos", "pertinent" ou encore "topique" comme antonyme de hors-sujet. Moi je dirais "dans le propos".

Comment: OK, so what would the french be for: `as long as the question would have been on-topic`?

Comment: J'aurais plutôt dit "à*-*propos" - mais je préfère "pertinent".

Comment: @Jez "Tant que la question reste en relation avec le sujet" ?

Comment: @Sylvain J'ai mis "tant que la question serait appropriée pour le site".

Comment: Et qu'on banisse toutes les questions impertinentes de ce site!

Comment: +1 pour "pertinent"

Comment: "Pertinent" est clair et sonne français

Answer (score 16):

In context, using your own translation:

> Yes, this should be fine, as long as the question would have been on-topic even if you didn't know the answer. Giving a good answer to a good question that you know beforehand can help the site be more useful.

With:

> Oui, il n'y a aucun problème avec ça, tant que la question est **pertinente**, même si on ne connait pas la bonne réponse. Donner une bonne réponse à une bonne question qu'on connait déjà peut aider à rendre le site plus utile.

Answer (score 10):

### À propos (adj.) / à-propos (loc. adv.)

Oui, ça a déjà été proposé. Alors, pourquoi le reproposer ? Pour faire un commentaire un peu long sur la différence entre **à propos** et **à-propos**. On trouve des partisans des deux dans les commentaires, alors que la différence est bien établie (*TLF*, Littré, etc.):

- *à propos* est une locution adverbiale.
- *à-propos* est un substantif (masculin) désignant « ce qui est à propos ».

Donc, dans notre cas, la question est (ou n'est pas) *à propos*. C'est sur son *à-propos* que nous devons discuter et voter.

Answer (score 9):

Il n'y a pas de traduction exacte. « *Off-topic* » correspond exactement à « hors-sujet », mais ce terme n'a pas d'antonyme clair. Une possibilité est donc de tourner la clause négativement, par exemple pour « *as long as the question would have been on-topic* » : « sauf si la question aurait été hors-sujet » (attention, si + conditionnel peut choquer certains) ou « à moins que la question n'eût été hors-sujet » (attention, imparfait du subjonctif, registre très soutenu) ou « du moment que la question n'aurait pas été hors-sujet ».

Sinon, il y a des mots qui peuvent convenir sans être franchement synonymes. Pour déterminer si une question est appropriée pour le site, j'utilise plutôt en anglais « *appropriate* » ou « *suitable* » (plus larges que « *on-topic* » qui ne regarde que le sujet de la question et pas la façon dont elle est posée ni le genre qu'elle appelle). Donc, en français, j'utiliserais naturellement des mots tels que « approprié » ou « adapté » ou « bienvenu ». Si on veut vraiment insister sur le sujet du site, on peut dire que la question « rentre dans le sujet du site » (par exemple, la question « comment appelle-t-on en français l'animal appelé « *dog* » en anglais ? » est bien dans le sujet de ce site mais n'y est pas appropriée).

Comment: "approprié" n'est pas mal, en effet

Answer (score 4):

« dans le thème » p.e. « Keep your questions on topic », « Gardez vos questions dans le thème du site. »

Comment: « Thème » est plus large que « sujet », on peut être hors-sujet tout en restant dans le thème. Par exemple, si le sujet est la traduction de *on-topic*, le thème est celui de la traduction. Et je pense que *on-topic* correspond plus au sujet qu'au thème.

Comment: Je suis d'accord que « thème » est plus large.  Mais j'aurais tendance à utiliser « sujet » pour la question et « thème » pour le site.

Answer (score 0):

Selon moi, on peut la traduire par "à propos". Mais j'admet que ce n'est pas idéal.

Comment: à-propos, alors

Comment: @Jourbarc à propos de ce tiret, voir ma réponse :)

Comment: @F'x Je suis debout corrigé. (I stand corrected)