# Expression « pour une déterminer qqch » — correct ou non?

Tags: expressions, grammaire

J'étudie le français et dans un texte que je lis pour mes études j'ai trouvé l'expression « pour une déterminer qqch ».

Cette expression existe-t-elle ou est-ce que « une » avant le verbe est une erreur d'impression ?

Answer (score 4):

C'est une erreur d'impression. (Étonnamment, elle semble apparaître à plusieurs endroits, voir commentaires).

La formulation correcte est « pour déterminer quelque chose ».
(Le sens de *déterminer* est assez variable. Lorsque l'objet est « quelque chose », son sens est proche de *identifier*, *préciser*, *caractériser*, *définir*, *délimiter*, *évaluer*, *fixer*, *qualifier*, voire même *spécifier*, *choisir* ou *décider*…)

Comment: Hmm! Je vois quelques occurrences sur le net. @Gilles lui même l'[a utilisé](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/146/comment-traduire-on-topic/163#163). Il faut lui demander son avis.

Comment: C'est bien une erreur d'impression (enfin, plutôt de rédaction). Ça arrive souvent quand on change de structure grammaticale au milieu de l'écriture d'une phrase.

Comment: Merci beaucoup de vos réponses !